# Program to use an Xbox controller as a mouse

Tags: windows-10, mouse, game-controller, input-device

I recently bought an Xbox 360 controller for my computer (those things are really cheap now that the new Xbox is the norm) and I was trying to figure out if there was a way to use the controller as a mouse for normal, everyday use as well as for games. I looked into this about 6 months ago and found a program that would run in the background and translate your game controller input into keyboard and mouse input. Unfortunately I didn't save the link to the program and I can't find it again.

Does anyone know what this program was called and where I can find it?

I'm running Windows 10 with the Xbox controller and IR receiver.

If you need anymore information, let me know.

Comment: Sorry, questions that ask for software recommendations are off-topic here because they tend to go out of date quickly. You might be able to get help at [softwarerecs.se] after looking through their help center.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. I didn't know there was a software recommendations site. I'll be sure to use that next time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [XPadder](http://www.xpadder.com/?lang=english&country=US). It can interpretate inputs from any gamepad to a mouse/KB commands.
I'm not sure its very comfortable to use XBox controller as mouse for everyday usege, but you can configure to use analog sticks as mouse. From my expirience it reminds using the trackpoint (or pointing stick).

Answer (score 0):

[AntiMicro](https://github.com/AntiMicro/antimicro) is an open-source alternative to XPadder and one of the best programs I've used for achieving this.